# How can I add git clone operation in inline groovy script

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I want to clone repo using inline groovy script in jenkins. How can I execute git clone and build the app using groovy.

Comment: I use the following, but I actually don't know if it works in other jenkins environments `node { checkout scm }`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using Jenkins pipelines, see examples from the official [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/), e.g.:

```
node {
    stage('Clone sources') {
        git url: 'https://github.com/jfrogdev/project-examples.git'
    }
}
```

For simple Groovy script you can try something like:

```
 ["git", "clone", "https://github.com/jfrogdev/project-examples.git"].execute()
```

Answer (score 2):

i also do something similar:

jenkinsfile / or pipeline script code:

```
node
{
    stage('Checkout')
    {
        GitManager.clone(this, "https://github.com/jfrogdev/project-examples.git", "*/master", "myGitUserID");
    }
}
```

utility class code (from sharedLib):

```
class GitManager
{
    public static void clone(Script scriptRef, String gitURLString, String branchID, String gitUserID)
    {
        scriptRef.checkout([
            $class: 'GitSCM', 
            branches: [[name: branchID]], 
            doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
            extensions: [[$class: 'CleanCheckout']], 
            submoduleCfg: [], 
            userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: gitUserID, url: gitURLString]]
        ])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: Clone of github repo and on this step installing the dependencies throw and so solution is

**Solution:**
Do git clone & install dependencies on one line

```
  stage('Clone the project and Delete the existing folder') { 
        steps {
           sh 'rm -rf jenkin-learn'
           sh 'git clone --single-branch --branch main https://github.com/mabdullahse/jenkin-learn.git && cd ./jenkin-learn && npm install' 
        }
    }
```